# Ordering the Sets of Levels of a variable in the X-axis of a Grouped Bar Chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have created a grouped bar chart with ggplot2. I have named this table as "data3" and the table looks like this -

```
Menopausal_Status   Depression_Status     Percent
Peri                      Mild           20.83333
Post                      Mild           68.75000
Pre                       Mild           10.41667
Peri                    Moderate         23.46369
Post                    Moderate         15.08380
Pre                     Moderate         61.45251
Peri              Moderately Severe      26.86567
Post              Moderately Severe      26.86567
Pre               Moderately Severe      46.26866
Peri                      Severe         28.12500
Post                      Severe         37.50000
Pre                       Severe         34.37500
```

The codings are given below -

```
library(ggplot2)
p1 = ggplot(data3)+ geom_bar (aes (x = Menopausal_Status,
                               y= Percent,
                               fill = Depression_Status),
                               stat = "identity",
                          position = position_dodge(0.8))
p1
```

These codings produced this graph.

[image]

So, I wanted to reorder the levels/factors of the variable "Menopausal_Status" in the x-axis of this graph like this

"Pre", "Peri", "Post"

I have tried the scale_x_discrete() function.

```
p1 = ggplot(data3)+ geom_bar (aes (x = Menopausal_Status,
                               y= Percent,
                               fill = Depression_Status),
                               stat = "identity",
                          position = position_dodge(0.8))+
scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Pre", "Peri", "Post"))
p1
```

But this produced this graph with this warning message- 
**"Warning message:
Removed 4 rows containing missing values (geom_bar).**

[image]

In where did I have done the wrong? Can you suggest a better way to reorder the levels of a variable in a  grouped bar plot?

```
dput(data3)
```

This is the output -

```
`structure(list(Menopausal_Status = c("Peri", "Post", "Pre ", 
"Peri", "Post", "Pre ", "Peri", "Post", "Pre ", "Peri", "Post", 
"Pre "), Depression_Status = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Mild", "Moderate", "Moderately 
Severe", 
"Severe"), class = "factor"), Percent = c(20.8333333333333, 68.75, 
10.4166666666667, 23.463687150838, 15.0837988826816, 61.4525139664804, 
26.865671641791, 26.865671641791, 46.2686567164179, 28.125, 37.5, 
34.375)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")`
```

Comment: can you do levels(data3$Menopausal_Status) and see whether the levels are correct? I think there might something weird about the column

Comment: @StupidWolf  Actually the same table produces the 1st graph. So, I think the table is ok. It is a 2x2 table and I have converted it into data frame using "as.data.frame.matrix" code to produce the graph with ggplot2.

Comment: do you mind doing dput(data3) and paste the output as part of your post?

Comment: @StupidWolf I have added the output of dput(data3).

Comment: You have an extra space in "Pre ". Try `scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Pre ", "Peri", "Post"))`

Comment: @dc37 Thanks, dear. It solves the problem.

Comment: you're welcome ;) @StupidWolf put you on the track by asking for the `dput` ;)

Comment: @dc37 yes you are right. Thanks to StupidWolf too.